# PIL: How to draw shapes given a set of unordered outline dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-imaging-library, shapes

I am using Python version 3.8.7 and the PIL library.

I have a DataFrame full of dimensions of various elements of a blueprint. The two main elements are lines (composing the outline), and the labels (colored rectangles). Using PIL I was able to draw the below image.

[image]

However, I would like to fill in each room as the same color as the respective label that falls within it. Right now I only have the dimensions (coordinates) of the lines forming the outline and the dimensions of the labels. Each dimension value (coordinate) is as follows:

```
(x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max)
```

The appropriate color for each label is predefined.

The lists are both unordered and I am wondering how I can fill in area within the outlines with the correct color for each of the labeled rooms. Some interesting notes, are that some lines, though they appear to be one straight coherent line, are actually composed of multiple lines.

In case it is needed, the code for drawing a rectangle is:

```
                #Dimensions/coordinates    # Color                # Outline Color
draw.rectangle((200, 100, 300, 200), fill=(0, 192, 192), outline=(255, 255, 255))
```

I am unsure how I can complete this task.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You mention several different kinds of outlines. Where do the outlines of the rooms themselves come from and how are they drawn? That is when their interiors should also be filled in. PIL doesn't have a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) drawing method where you give it a point in the interior of a closed shape and it colors the rest of inside of area - although you might be able to implement your own.

Comment: @martineau I am unsure what you mean by several kinds of outlines. There is just a collection of dimensions for lines that form an outline. Inside each shape formed by the outline there is a label (coordinates for the labels are also stored in a list). I would like to fill each shape with the color of the label. I am aware that PIL does not have a method for this but I am struggling to find a way to implement it on my own.

Comment: I was mistaken, an experimental `floodfill()` [implementation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill) has been added to PIL. To use it you will need to determine which room each label is inside of in order to determine what fill color to use. If you know in advance that the outline of each label is in the room, that should be relatively easy.

Comment: P.S. What I meant about several kinds of outlines is, first you say "I have a DataFrame of outlines for a blueprint", followed by "I have a list of the dimensions of the outlines", and that you are "also given the coordinates of labels for each shape/room". Is your question is unclear in the sense that I'm unsure whether it's asking how to fill the room outlines with a color or how to determine what color to use to fill them (base on the label coordinates).

Comment: @martineau The problem is that each outline is composed of individual lines some straight lines are even composed of multiple lines. There is no information beforehand about the location of the labels relative to the general outline. That is what makes the problem difficult.

Comment: I have made the appropriate changes to the question to address the confusion. I hope this explains it better. I am extremely stumped and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your update helped. Since you (apparently) know where to place each label, it means you also know a point inside each room outline (e.g. the midpoint of each label) — so, after drawing the room outlines you can then use `floodfill()` along with each label's color to fill them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the expected result:

[image]

You can use this pseudo-code:

```
for thisColour in list of blob colours (1)
   generate list of neighbours 1-pixel outside this blob (2)
   for thisNeighbour in list of neighbours
      if thisNeighbour is currently white
         floodfill with thisColour from thisNeighbour as seed (3)
```

1. You should have a list of the coloured blobs.
2. This is simple maths, as your coloured blobs are all rectangles, you just need to subtract 1 from the x,y of the top-left corner of the blob and add 1 to the x,y of the bottom-right corner. So if your blob is at 8,10 to 100,110 the neighbours are the points along the sides of the rectangle 7,9 to 99,109. `scikit-image` has a [rectangle_perimter()](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.rectangle_perimeter) that will also do this for you. If your blobs were any complicated shape, you could use a morphological opening to get them.
3. Use [floodfill()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html?highlight=floodfill#PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill) for this.

---

By the way, think twice before using JPEG format for image processing, as it is lossy and distorts colours and you end up having to add *"fudge factors"* and tolerances everywhere to allow for the *"errors"* it introduces. It's often preferable, especially with blocky computer-generated graphics such as yours to use PNG format which is lossless.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input! These results are indeed what I am seeking. Can you explain step 2. a little further. What do you mean by "blob is at 8,10 to 100,110." The issue is that the lines forming the outlines are not one coherent shape nor are they always one line. After reading your answer I am getting the sense that perhaps PIL is not the best for what I am doing. Do you recommend something else, perhaps skimage?

Comment: They should correspond more or less exactly to your points `(x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max)` which define the top-left and bottom-right corners of your coloured blobs. Your coloured blobs **are** rectangles as shown in your image, aren't they?